# Downsampling an image without "dancing" pixels

Tags: graphics, hlsl, cg

Say I wanted to downsample an image in realtime (1280x720) to a very small scale (16x16) and not suffer from "dancing" pixels when the image moves, which technique would I use?

This would be using XBox360/PS3 GPUs.

Note that the 16x16 image only needs to contain a very "generalised" representation of the original image - almost like a rough-estimate of colour.

Doing a direct downsample results in pixels coming in/out of the sampling so you get a dancing/disco effect when the image moves.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use averaging instead of downsampling. For instance, setting each pixel to the average value of an 80x45 pixel block will give you a 16x16 image from a 1280x720 image. Note that that would alter the aspect ratio though...

I should clarify that you don't necessarily have to average the entire block -- you could average every other pixel in it or whatever you want. But the more pixels you account for, the more accurate the value would be. You could also use other statistical measures -- the mode or median values across channels could also work.

Comment: Averaging is a very poor low pass filter. Better to use a decent  filter prior to decimation.

Comment: That'd work too -- just run a Gaussian filter or something over the whole image before downsampling. I'm not sure exactly what makes averaging so poor though. It can be very fast, although I presume you're referring to the fact that it's anisotropic?

Comment: I've found that simple box averaging often looks just as good or better than much more complicated filters such as Gauss, Sinc, Mitchell, Bessel, or Kaiser at a fraction of the computional cost. But that somewhat depends on your taste too, I guess.

Comment: @aardvarkk: the problem with using averaging instead of a decent low pass filter is that averaging has very poor stop-band rejection, so you get significant unwanted high frequency energy which then results in aliassing. For many applications though this may not matter, but for high quality downsampling it's better to use a decent filter.

Comment: Median filtering (or in general ordinal statistics filtering) is a very effective way to downsample. Median selection can be done in linear time, though it requires a lot of conditional branching as opposed to averaging algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The downsampling filter that will give the best quality is to do a 2D Fourier transform, select only the low frequencies and do an inverse Fourier transform into the low resolution image.

Obviously this won't be the fastest method and there may be minor issues with scaling and handling the color channels.